# Remember camera access settings without asking in the next page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two pages - `new` and `show`. In new.html.erb I `render partial` that has `javascript_include_tag` which asks for camera access. So far it works fine. Now the previous code renders the same partial in `show.html.erb` also. So whenever the user goes to `show` it asks for camera access again before showing the content. What I want is not to ask the user again for camera access in `show` page since the user has already selected `allow` button in the `new` page. So how can I make the next page i.e., `show` page remember that `camera access` has been allowed in `new` previously and not to show the camera access pop-up but keep the camera on?

Comment: Might want to show the JS snippet, of how you're requesting/using camera access, at a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: Should I add js code also or only html.erb?